# Adjusting color temperature on ImageView

Tags: android, image-processing, colormatrix

I successfully implemented functionality to adjust the contrast and/or brightness of an ImageView via values coming from user's SeekBars selections. For the contrast it looks like that (similar for brightness):

```
// Contrast
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.set(new float[] {
        scale, 0, 0, 0, translate,   // Red
        0, scale, 0, 0, translate,   // Green
        0, 0, scale, 0, translate,   // Blue
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });            // Alpha

imageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
```

So I could adjust the contrast and/or brightness just by scaling (multiplication) or translating (addition) the RGB values with another value.

How can I do the same thing (using a matrix) for adjusting the image's color temperature?

Answer (score 3):

I just created such a Matrix for my application to adjust the color temperature.

```
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();

colorMatrix.set(new float[] {
RED/255.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, GREEN/255.0f, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, BLUE/255.0f, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0}); 
imageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
```

The values for RED, GREEN and BLUE you can get for example from here:
http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html

It works perfectly fine and even images with a very strong color temperature can be adjusted accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed **destiny** answer, but had to do some adjustment, here is how i did it:

```
let amount = 255;
let value  = 0;

(1.0000* amount)/255.0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, ((1.0000+value)* amount)/255.0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, ((1.0000+value)* amount)/255.0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```